# Implementing element-wise ufunc using numba with variable number of input and output arguments

Tags: python, numpy, performance, simulation, numba

I'm working on a system simulator in Python. I'm trying to allow for custom system blocks using element-wise functions. Numpy provides a the function "frompyfunc" to create a universal function from a python function. I'm looking to do the same thing, but using numba. The problem is I can't figure out how to do this with variable number of input and output arguments.

The motivation behind this effort is that numba is very quick in testing. The example below:

```
def nb_frompyfunc(func):
    nb_ufunc = nb.njit(func)
    @nb.njit
    def inner(x, y):
        out = np.zeros_like(x)
        for i in range(x.shape[0]):
            for j in range(x.shape[1]):
                out[i, j] = nb_ufunc(x[i, j], y[i, j])
        return out
    return inner

func = lambda x, y: x + y

np_func = np.frompyfunc(func, 2, 1)
nb_func = nb_frompyfunc(func)

x = np.random.rand(1000, 1000)
y = np.random.rand(1000, 1000)

# Force compile
nb_func(x, y)

print('Numpy ufunc time:')
%timeit np_func(x, y)
print('Numba ufunc time:')
%timeit nb_func(x, y)
```

Yields the following results:

```
Numpy ufunc time:
78.7 ms ± 516 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
Numba ufunc time:
1.05 ms ± 15.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Numba comes out ~80x faster when processing 1000 x 1000 blocks of data.

Unfortunately the numba solution above assumes the number of input and output arguments. I'd like the numba function generator to take the number of input and output arguments as inputs just like the numpy solution. The function would have the following signature:

`nb_frompyfunc(func, nargin, nargout)`

The pythonic solution using varargin is unfortunately not supported by the "nopython" mode for numba.

I experimented with dynamic code generation, but it appears that I'd have to save the new code to a temporary python file and import it as a module. This solution should work, but I don't like the idea of generating temporary files. If I could get the dynamic code working without saving to a file, then I really like this approach.

The other solution I came up with was to have multiple generators that are selected based on the number of arguments, but it's not a very elegant solution. It also imposes a limit on arguments based on how many pre-written generators are provided.

What is good way to solve this problem? I'm not beholden to my current approach. As long as a vectorized function is created that is also very quick, I'll be happy. My fallback plan will be to just use the numpy implementation, which is likely good enough. My main concern is if these system are ever deployed into production, they need to be able to handle data as quickly as possible.

edit: added clarification.

Comment: Note that `np.empty_like` is faster than using `np.zeros_like` here (the later is not needed in this case).

Comment: *"assumes the number of input and output arguments"* Yes, but if my understanding is correct, the user function is the lambda and `nb_frompython` is the one you provide and this one already make assumption about the number of input and output so Numba does not seems to add more constraints. I'm struggling to find cases where the variable number of arguments can be useful (except maybe if you are dealing with a variable number of dimensions which cause a lot of complications with Numba unless you use vectorize decorators).

Comment: I would have multiple pre-selected numba versions and fallback python method if number of arguments does not match any of those. Also, don't try to solve problems that may never occur. Write complete first version of the simulator and see if the performance will be an an issue here

Comment: The empty_like does improve it quite a bit. Comes in about 5x faster. It also helps to reshape and use a single loop.

The variable arguments is a very useful thing. The other two arguments for "np.frompython" are for the number of input and output arguments.

Comment: Numba provides [vectorize](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/vectorize.html) to create universal functions. It is common to use it as a decorator, as in the documentation, but you could also try `nb_ufunc = nb.vectorize(func)`.

Comment: I was not aware of the vectorize decorator! That seems to do exactly what I was wanting to achieve. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Numba's vectorize is what I was looking for.

For exmaple.
`ufunc = nb.vectorize(lambda x, y: x + y)`

I was not aware of numba's vectorize decorator. Thank you Ken for showing that to me in the comments.